# jQuery ajax data two variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I'm trying to send some data via ajax with jquery

```
var name = $(".name").attr("data-name");
var value = $(".value").attr("data-value");

$.ajax({
    url: 'panel.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {name: value}
}).done(function(){
    alert("saved!");
});
```

So how can name and value be two variables. Now only value is a variable but what about name?

Cheers

Comment: Build your object before the call and set the name attribute there.

Comment: where is your on error function?  I know some people like the .done() functionality, but i think it would look nicer if you have success and error in the {}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
var name = "data-name";
var value = "data-value";
var dataObj = {};

dataObj[name]=value;

$.ajax({
    url: 'panel.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: dataObj,
}).done(function(){
    alert("saved!");
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it to a DTO (Data Transfer object):

```
var obj = {};
obj.name = name;
obj.value = value;

//Convert to a DTO Object
var dto = { 'myData': obj };
```