# stack level too deep when posting long nested list in ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, post, rack, nested-lists

I'm posting a long nested list that looks like this image on firebug:

[long nested list http://i.imm.io/1m4s2.jpeg](http://i.imm.io/1m4s2.jpeg)

While you can see in the same image that the post is successful, the only thing that appears on the log is the following lines:

`[2013-12-11 20:50:37] ERROR SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    /home/fotanus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:527`

And no action seems to be executed on Rails.

The long list is being sent with the following line:

`$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: '/projects', data: JSON.stringify({ sortd_items: sorted_items }) })`

where `sorted_items` is printed in the image, generated by a recursive function.

Why this is happening, and how can I make things work as expected?

**Edit:** Using a smaller list seems to work:

`Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-11 21:01:08 -0200
Processing by ProjectsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"{\"sortd_items\":"=>{"\"2\","=>{"\"5\","=>[{",\"6\","=>[{",\"7\","=>[{",\"8\","=>[{",\"3\","=>{"\"10\","=>[{",\"10\","=>[{",\"4\","=>[{",\"5\","=>[{",\"6\","=>[{",\"7\","=>[{",\"8\","=>[{",\"3\","=>{"\"10\","=>[{",\"10\","=>[{",\"4\","=>[{",\"9\","=>{"\"11\","=>[{",\"12\","=>{"\"13\","=>[{",\"14\","=>[{",\"15\","=>[{",\"13\","=>[{",\"14\","=>[{",\"15\","=>[{",\"11\","=>[{",\"12\","=>{"\"13\","=>[{",\"14\","=>[{",\"15\","=>[{",\"13\","=>[{",\"14\","=>[{",\"15\","=>[{"}"=>nil}]}]}]}]}]}]}}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}}]}}]}]}]}}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}}]}]}]}]}}}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms`

But I need to make it work with large lists as well.

Comment: How exactly are you posting this data? It seems like what might be happening is that you're posting an object that isn't particularly deep (maybe about a depth of 5, max), but it's going to a part of Rack that's trying to parse it in a different format, which ends up creating a very deep hash instead of what it's intending to do. Namely, I think you may be sending the server an improperly encoded query string.

Comment: @Bubbles `How exactly are you posting this data?` I have copy the line from my javascript file that posts the data - if you need something else, sorry, I failed to understand. How exactly I check if my string is properly encoded? `JSON.stringfy` don't assure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rack utils.rb method `to_params_hash` does indeed recurse. It does that because, per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , `$.ajax()` treats the `data:` variable as a string containing URL query parameters.

Put together, Rails treats each key in your nested structure as something that you want to see in your `params` hash. You don't; you just need to pass all that JSON as a string, so your own methods can safely decode it as JSON, using a C JSON library that (probably) won't abuse the stack.

Per [jQuery ajax data two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368588/jquery-ajax-data-two-variables) , you might be able to stuff the string into a hash and pass the hash:

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj[json]=JSON.stringify({ sortd_items: sorted_items });
$.ajax({ ... data: dataObj });
```

​
Now `$.ajax()` won't see a string, won't convert it into query params, and won't bust Rack.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be testing this tonight and will let you know

Comment: Will award you extra 100 points tomorrow, when stackoverflow let me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a matter of properly setting the headers in the ajax request properly. You can post data that has been put through `JSON.stringify`, but the server won't know what to do with it unless you tell it what it's getting. This should fix it:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/projects',
  contentType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({ sortd_items: sorted_items })
})
```